# Recommendation for book on $\pi$?

Tags: reference-request, pi

I'm looking for a book that goes over the history of $\pi$, the mathematics of $\pi$ (like a discussion about the possible proof that all ten digits 0-9 occur with equal probability, viz., $\pi$'s normality), and all the historical and recent methods for computing the digits of $\pi$.

Comment: In general you don't want to ask what the "best" is since this will depend on opinion. I hope you approve of the edit.

Comment: I would also very much like to see a book which proves that all digits in the decimal expansion of $\pi$ appear with equal probability, considering that it is not currently known if all digits even appear infinitely often.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try these excellent books:

- [The Number $\pi$](http://www.ams.org/bookstore-getitem/item=tnp) by Eymard and Lafon.
- [Pi: A Source Book](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4757-2736-4) by  Berggren, Borwein, and Borwein.

Comment: Wow, Berggren, Borwein, & Borwein is exactly the sort of work I was looking for, since it's partially an anthology! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

In French (as I know not translated to English) *The fascinant nombre pi* is wonderful. Research-level about pi-approximating algorithms, *Pi and the AGM*. And the proof of normality of $\pi$ is... still unknown.

Answer (score 2):

For a more historical account, "A History of PI" by Petr Backmann is nice.  It doesn't contain any advanced proofs though (it is more of a survey), and it doesn't have the modern results.

The most modern result for computing $\pi$ that I am aware of is the spigot algorithm, it allows you to compute the $n^{\text{th}}$ digit of $\pi$ in $O(\log(n))$ time (or maybe it was polylogarithmic).  It is very recent though, so for whatever book you choose, double check to make sure this result is present because is has been very important.

Comment: If you read *A History of Pi* prepare to be hit by Beckmann's shrill and incessant political commentary, which frequently includes name calling.

Comment: I don't recall him making any political comments, and especially not in regard to any modern political organization or positions.  He does; however, categorize several historical groups who stood in the way of mathematical progress as well as those who promoted it, in a very no-sugar-coating way.  I could have simply forgotten or been more sympathetic to the parts Bulberage is remembering though.

Comment: It's pretty good. The most recent substantial result it contains is Lindemann's famous proof of the transcendence of $\pi$, published in 1882.

Comment: Yes but it does not go into any detailed proofs, it just gives the results that were proven which led to the transcendence of $\pi$.